# AUCTeX cannot find a working Tex distribution and don't know how to install exec-path-from-shell

Tags: latex, auctex

When I was trying to export the pdf file. It notifies me this.
[image]
And then I searched on Google. People suggest me check the method in the link below.
https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell

But I got stuck on the first step, "add the following into your `init.el`."
Where is init.el??
And how to evaluate `(getenv "SHELL")` ??

Comment: Which system are you working on? OS X as purcell? Give the output of `emacs-version`. Which version of auctex do you use?

Comment: OS version: macOS High Sierra. Emacs version: 26.1

Comment: Do you have TeX installed? Open a terminal and enter the command `which tex`. What is the output? What is the output of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: `init.el` is a configuration file. It is usually located at `~/.emacs.d/init.el`. If this file isn't there, you can create it. An alternative to `init.el` is to put this sort of stuff in a file `~/.emacs`.

Comment: To evaluate `(getenv "SHELL")`, put that code into the emacs scratch buffer, put the cursor after the closing parenthesis, and type `C-x C-e`.

Answer (score 2):

A short answer: for your path problem you can use of course the package `exec-path-from-shell` or, shorter, use the following shorter code snippet in your `init.el` file:

```el
(setenv "PATH" (concat "/Library/TeX/texbin:"
                       (getenv "PATH")))
(add-to-list 'exec-path "/Library/TeX/texbin")
```

As for the `init.el` file: it is possible that you already have it. Usually it is hidden, so it will not show up in your Finder. Try the following:

- In your Finder, select your home folder and then type `cmd + >` to see all hidden files.
- Check for a folder `.emacs.d` in your home directory - if you don't already have it, then create it by choosing from menu File | Create New Folder and type in the name `.emacs.d`.
- Now open your Emacs and then create the file `init.el`, by opening with:
  `C-x C-f` and then from the minibuffer type `~/.emacs.d/init.el`.
- Place here the above snippet and the rest of your configurations.