# AucTeX with emacs28.0.50

Tags: latex, auctex, tex

I want to compile my LaTeX files with `emacs28.0.50`. I was receiving the same error that is described in [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/43731/30325) question. I followed the instructions given in the accepted answer and now my `init.el` file looks like this -

```
(setq gnutls-algorithm-priority "NORMAL:-VERS-TLS1.3")
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(package-selected-packages '(auctex org)))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )
(setenv "PATH" (concat "/Library/TeX/texbin:"
                     (getenv "PATH")))
(add-to-list 'exec-path "/Library/TeX/texbin")
```

I still get the same error. Have I done something wrong? If yes please let me know what exactly is wrong. Also I need to change the default compiler to `LuaLaTeX`. If somebody knows how to do it, please tell me.

Comment: Are you on OS X? The path they used for getting to the the TeX processor(s) is specific to that operating system (and perhaps to that particular installation). Yours may be different: assuming you are on a Unix-like OS (Mac OS X or Linux or BSD), you can try `which pdflatex` and see where that is found.

Comment: I suggest to read at least chapter 1 of this page: https://protesilaos.com/dotemacs/ - for details of init.el file - it will be useful to use ```use-package``` package for your configuration. Then this: https://github.com/dangom/emacs.d#latex will show you an example for configuration of latex/lua. (This uses evil keybindings, so you may omit them).

Comment: "Also I need to..." Please, only one question per question. Pose other questions separately.

Comment: Please edit your question to make it self-contained. Show the error message. And please explain how this question is not a duplicate of the one you reference.

Comment: @NickD Thanks! That solved my problem. I don't mind deleting the question if other users find it repetitive :) Please let me know

Comment: @Ian Thanks, I will have a look at both of them.

Comment: @Drew You are right, that question solves my problem.